# symfony doctrine get original count of a filtered child row

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My entity "parent" is in relation with the entity "child" in a OneToMany context. parent have many childs.

I need to filter these childs matching some condition. In this case an valid child id list.

I want to get only parents with ALL and ONLY child matching the condition. For now, with the code below I can get childs matching the condition but also which having child out of the condition.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.childs','c','with','c.child IN (:child_list)')
            ->having('count(c) = :count_child')
            ->groupBy('s')
            ->setParameter('child_list',$childs)
            ->setParameter('count_child',count($childs))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getScalarResult()
            ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is:

- Inner Join with all childs without condition
- Create a computed value using **CASE ... THEN ... ELSE**, where it sets the value to 1 if the child.id is in the child_list and 0 if not
- sum the above computed value
- check whether SUM(value) = count(child_list)

Change to:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin('p.childs','c')
            ->addSelect('SUM(case when c.id IN (:child_list) then 1 else 0 end) as HIDDEN totalFound');
            ->having('totalFound = :count_child AND count(c) = :count_child')
            ->groupBy('p')
            ->setParameter('child_list',$childs)
            ->setParameter('count_child',count($childs))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getScalarResult()
            ;
```